# Hereditarily finitely presented groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

We call a group $G$ hereditarily finitely presentable if all its subgroups are finitely presentable. Finite groups and finitely generated Abelian groups are hfp. Free groups $F_n$ for $n > 1$ are not hfp, since they contain $F_{\infty}$. What other classes of examples of such groups are there? What are the necessary conditions? Maybe we can (in a sense) describe them all. I can't find anything about this on the internet.

Comment: I had the impression there were no functional definitions of this concept, beyond the tautological, and that's the primary reason you see so little discussion of the concept in the literature.  That said, I certainly do not know all of combinatorial group theory.

Comment: What does functional definitions mean? Do you mean that this concept is very difficult to learn and / or not of interest? I just got this concept in the context of some natural question and I became curious about what is known about such groups, how many examples there are.

Comment: A related commonly studied notion is that of a coherent group (=every finitely generated subgroup is finitely presented), see e.g. https://blog.spp2026.de/coherent-groups/.

Comment: Thank you! This gives the necessary condition. HFP = coherence + all subgroups are finitely generated.

Comment: By "functional" I mean there being a reasonable list of things to check.

Comment: Finitely generated nilpotent groups satisfy this condition. In fact, more generally, so do virtually polycyclic groups.

Comment: Almost certainly the situation is the same as for slender (i.e. hereditarily fg) groups: every known (finitely presented) example is virtually polycyclic, but a proof that there are no other known examples, or alternatively a construction of a more interesting example, is way beyond current technology.

Comment: @HJRW such groups are by definition finitely presented. So, as you say, the only known examples are virtually polycyclic.